# What is the correct way to import files within subfiles?

Tags: input, include, paths, import, subfiles

The `subfiles` [docs](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) explains that it handles path issues when main files and subfiles are in different directories and subfiles contain paths relative to their own directories using the `\import` package. [It appears](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676872/how-do-relative-paths-work-with-the-subfile-package/678053#678053) that this means `subfiles` uses `\import` when adding the content of files passed to `\subfile`. For example, `\subfile{ch/ch1.tex}` is roughly equivalent to modifying the preamble of `ch1.tex` then calling `\import{ch/ch1.tex}`. What is not clear is how to correctly **nest imports**, i.e. import within imported subfiles.

Below I provide an example project/directory structure and two example files assuming that main.tex should import ch1.tex and ch1.tex should import fig.png and text.txt.

```
 +-- main.tex
 +-- chapters
     |
     +-- ch1.tex
     +-- content
         |
         +-- text1.txt
         +-- fig1.png
```

```tex
%% main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \subfile{chapters/ch1.tex} % \imports ch1.tex
\end{document}
```

```tex
%% ch1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \import{content}{text.txt}        % adds some text - note use of \import
    \includegraphics{content/fig.png} % adds a figure
\end{document}
```

When I compile the files above, they produce the desired output. However, as `\import` is used in the `\subfile{chapters/ch1.tex}` call in main.tex but then is *also* used *within* ch1.tex in the `\import{content}{text.txt}` call. The `import` [docs](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) indicates `\subimport` should be used for the latter. As \subimport`requires a path relative to the currently imported file, the call should be`\subimport{content/}{text1.txt}`.

Should importing within subfiles always use `subimport`? If so, I am confused as to why swapping `\import` with `\subimport` produces the same results when they should presumably point to different directories as in the examples in the `import` docs.

Comment: Because standalone compilation is great.

Comment: @socialscientist You could typeset parts of a document by commenting/uncommenting `\input` statements. I.e., you typeset each time the main document, but change which `\input` statements are active. This is robust and compatible with all packages. `subfiles` has to do modify the `\end` command, which is potentially harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\input` directly.

```
│  main.tex
│
└─chapters
    │  ch1.tex
    │
    └─content
            fig1.png
            text1.txt
```

`main.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{chapters/content/}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\input@path}{{chapters/}{chapters/content/}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
aaa
\input{ch1.tex}
bbb
\end{document}
```

`ch1.tex`

```latex
ccc
\input{text1.txt}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
ddd
```

`text1.txt`

```
eee
```

[image]